# Ubuntu 12.04 audio playback silent (Vista stutters, Fedora normal)

Tags: 12.04, sound

Suddenly & without warning, I lost playback audio in Ubuntu 12.04. No startup sound, no MP3's, no YouTube audio. I downloaded the Pulse Audio Volume Control application; it animates sound that is supposed to be playing.

My system is dual-boot. When I boot into Windows Vista, I get the sound, but it stutters; that is, I get a half-second of sound, followed by an instant of silence, and this sequence repeats, yielding a choppy sound, as though coming from the other side of a spinning fan.

Finally I tried a Fedora LiveUSB. Sound is fine.

I'm mostly concerned with Ubuntu here, as that is my primary system. I include the output of the `aplay -l` command below. Thanks in advance.

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC268 Analog [ALC268 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC268 Digital [ALC268 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Update:** In the morning I booted into Ubuntu and all sound worked fine. I booted into Windows and the sound was working there too. Then I booted back into Ubuntu and they were no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the solution with the help of [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/pulseaudio-no-sound-only-dummy-output-4175437210/).

Around the time I installed Pianobar and Pithos, I installed the Roar audio server (not sure why; presumably as part of one of those installations). Roar seems subsequently to have taken over management of the audio. Uninstalling `roaraudio` and its dependencies solved the problem immediately.